# How to check if user has read/write permission for a SPListItem in c#?

Tags: development, permissions, splistitem, visual-web-part

In my SP2010 visual webpart, I am checking permissions with the code below. Basically the current user is either an admin or a regular user. If they are an admin, they need to have permission to edit properties of the item and read properties of the item. And if they are a regular user, they need to have permissions to read properties from items.

I think my code is doing more than whats required, like it may be doing redundent checks. Does anyone know whats the best way to check?

Thanks.

```
    public bool have_permissions_for_item(bool isEditMode, SPListItem item, Report RO)
    {
        try
        {
            // skip documents if user doesn't have access
            if (!item.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.ViewListItems)) return false;
            // skip documents if user doesn't have access
            if (!item.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.OpenItems)) return false;
            // skip documents if user doesn't have access
            if (!item.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.Open)) return false;
            if (isEditMode)
            {
                // skip documents if user doesn't have access
                if (!item.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.EditListItems)) return false;
            }
        }
        // catch the permission denied error so it doesn't ask the user for their credentials
        catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException F)
        {
            RO.log(Report.get_error_info(F));
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it better to use SharePoint group? You can create group whith predefined permissions, then checks if the user is a member of this group.

```
web.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(group.Id);
```